# Why doesn't this binary_search function return 5?

Tags: f#

This f# program does a binary search on an int array to find the first occurrence of a number.  Once it finds the number it prints the position and then returns it.  Then it prints the return value, but prints a different number.  I expected the same number.  Why is it different?

```
let int_array = [| 1; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 5; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 8; 9|]

let binary_search target (array:int[]) = 
    let rec bsearch found_pos start_i end_i  =
        let mid_i = start_i + (end_i-start_i) / 2
        if start_i = end_i then
            printfn "answer is %d" found_pos
            found_pos
        elif array.[ mid_i ] = target then
            bsearch mid_i start_i mid_i-1 
        elif array.[ mid_i ] < target then
            bsearch found_pos (mid_i+1) end_i
        else
            bsearch found_pos start_i (mid_i-1)
    bsearch -1 0 ((Array.length array)-1)


let ans = binary_search 5 int_array
printfn "but it returns %d" ans
```

Here is the output:

```
answer is 5
but it returns 3
```

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger to walk through your code?

Comment: I did.  It wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is missing parentheses. The code `bsearch mid_i start_i mid_i-1` is the same as `(bsearch mid_i start_i mid_i)-1`. If you change it to `bsearch mid_i start_i (mid_i-1)`, the first and final results will be the same.